# Why can I not hear any sound in this html code?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

That is the code, I dont hear the alarm and it doesnt make any sense to me.There is a file in the folder called alarm.mp3 but what ever file I name like this, doesn't show up. Any advice? I got the source code from a random website to make a gift  for someone, I modified some stuff (not effecting any of the sound stuff) and that is it. This code worked some days ago perfectly fine and now there is not audio output.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <style>
        .background-dark {
            background-color: #7fffd4;
        }
        .size1 {
            object-fit: scale-down;
        }
        .pic1 {
            margin-top: 15px;
            background-color: transparent;
            padding: 0;
border: none;
background: none;
         height:80px
}
img {
 width: auto;
 max-height: 100%;
}
.pic2 {
    margin-top: 100px;
height: 150px;
width: 200px;

}
.alarm {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #fff, -2px 0 0 #fff, 0 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 0 #fff, 1px 1px #fff, -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.uhrzeit {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    font-size: 45px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: -300px;
}
.input-1 {

    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.input2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 150px;
margin-right: -150px;
margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;

    height: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 5px solid #000;  border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 25px;

}
.button1 {
    margin-left: 160px;
    color: darkorange;
    border: 10px solid #000;  border-radius: 25px; border-style: double;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 35px;
    width: 250px;
}
.li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.button2 {

}
    </style>
</head>
<body class="background-dark">
    <div>



    </div>
</div>
<div class="pic2">
    <img src="img/bild2.png ">

    <div class="input-1">
        <input id="alarmTime" type="datetime-local" class="input2">
    </div>
    <div class="alarm">
        <button class="button1"  id="alarmButton" onclick="setAlarm(this);">bestätigen</button>
    </div>

    <div id="alarmOptions" style="display: none;">
        <button onclick="snooze();">Snooze 5 minutes</button>
        <button onclick="stopAlarm();">Stop Alarm</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var alarmSound = new Audio();
        var alarmSound = [
    "alarm.mp3",
  ];

        alarmSound.src = 'alarm.mp3';
        var alarmTimer;

        function setAlarm(button) {
            var ms = document.getElementById('alarmTime').valueAsNumber;
            if(isNaN(ms)) {
                alert('Invalid Date');
                return;
            }

            var alarm = new Date(ms);
            var alarmTime = new Date(alarm.getUTCFullYear(), alarm.getUTCMonth(), alarm.getUTCDate(),  alarm.getUTCHours(), alarm.getUTCMinutes(), alarm.getUTCSeconds());

            var differenceInMs = alarmTime.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();

            if(differenceInMs < 0) {
                alert('Specified time is already passed');
                return;
            }

            alarmTimer = setTimeout(initAlarm, differenceInMs);
            button.innerText = 'Cancel Alarm';
            button.setAttribute('onclick', 'cancelAlarm(this);');
        };

        function cancelAlarm(button) {
            clearTimeout(alarmTimer);
            button.innerText = 'Set Alarm';
            button.setAttribute('onclick', 'setAlarm(this);')
        };

        function initAlarm() {
            alarmSound.play();
            document.getElementById('alarmOptions').style.display = '';
        };

        function stopAlarm() {
            alarmSound.pause();
            alarmSound.currentTime = 0;
            document.getElementById('alarmOptions').style.display = 'none';
            cancelAlarm(document.getElementById('alarmButton'));
        };

        function snooze() {
            stopAlarm();
            alarmTimer = setTimeout(initAlarm, 300000); // 5 * 60 * 1000 = 5 Minutes
        };

    </script>
</body>
</html>´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this out:

`var alarmSound = [ "alarm.mp3", ]`

and try it again...

Comment: This answer would benefit greatly from an explanation as to *why* this helps to alleviate the issues the OP has described. (i.e., the line of code you cite *overwrites* the instance of `Audio` that was instantiated in the previous line, and removing this unnecessary line eliminates that and allows `alarmSound` to function as-intended as an `Audio` object)

Comment: srry esqew I was under the impression he needed a quick fix..